# how to echo print array in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

in mysql query results on  mysql command

```
language id   language name 
1               English
2               Hindi
3               Russian


$language_name =$conn->prepare("SELECT language_id, language_name FROM language_master");
                $language_name->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
                $language_name->execute();
                $language_name = $language_name->fetch();
```

How can i print /echo all languages and ids in php? like in a table.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = $language_name->fetch()) {
    $allRows[] = $row;
}
```

then in php

```
foreach($allRows as $value){
echo $value['language_id'];
}
```

Comment: sorry but last result just gave 123 for language names.. can u plz tell how to get list of language id and corrsesponding language name in a table with two column. I m new may be i m doing somthing worng in the msql query fetch etc.. plz check .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var_dump($language_name);
```

or

```
print_r($language_name);
```

to print the whole array.

---

**edit:**

so you can use as foreach-loop:

```
foreach($language_name as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key . ' => ' . $value;
   echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks maui for reply. but its not working. These are the resulets of above two.   array (size=4)
  'language_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'language_name' => string 'English' (length=7)
  1 => string 'English' (length=7)

Comment: and print_r($language_name); give only Array ( [language_id] => 1 [0] => 1 [language_name] => English [1] => English )    .....

Comment: i want to print all languages names with their keys. thanks

Comment: thanks maui but foreach give this result. i want to print the whole table. may be i m doing somthing wrong. i m new.  this the result of fore each language_id => 1
0 => 1
language_name => English
1 => English

Answer (score 0):

if i get you well, you want to show the result in a table.. use a loop to fetch the data. e.g

```
 <?php 
if(!empty($language_name)):  
$i = 0;
foreach($language_name as $rows): 
$i++;

echo $rows['language_id']; //for the language id
echo $rows['language_name ']; //for language name
endforeach; 
 endif; 
?>
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: an answer has been provided.. check again

Comment: Thanks Akinniyi ... yes you got me right . i just want to show languages id and names in a table a its showing on mysql .. i tried your solutin but it gives error --" Illegal string offset 'language_id' in.."  my edited code as per your solution is ---

Comment: $language_name =$conn->prepare("SELECT language_id, language_name FROM breakawayi.language_master where row_active=1");
     $language_name->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
     $language_name->execute();
     $language_name = $language_name->fetch();

 
if(!empty($language_name)):  
$i = 0;
foreach($language_name as $rows): 
$i++;

echo $rows['language_id']; //for the language id
echo $rows['language_name ']; //for language name
endforeach; 
 endif; 
"  i m just a biggner. Thanks for the help:)